# Context managers that also deal with sys.stdin and sys.stdout

Tags: python, io

It's pretty typical for Linux command-line utilities that deal with files to accept either a file as input, or `stdin`. It's also pretty common for them to be able to output to a file or to `stdout`.

These should be supported:

- `python myprogram.py input output`
- `cat input | python myprogram.py > output`
- `python myprogram.py input > output`

Additionally, I don't like editing files in-place. I'd rather make a tmpfile and then only copy over the tmpfile if the operation is a success, but I'd also rather not deal with tmpfiles every time I write something that has an output file. So both

- `python myprogram --in-place input`
- `python myprogram filename filename` (ie, input is the same as output)

should use a tmpfile.

I wrote this pair of context managers to make this type of interface a little easier to write. They're meant to be used something like this:

```
with infile(infile_filename) as f:
     for line in f: #do some stuff
with outfile(outfile_filename, infile_name=infile_filename, inplace=inplace) as f:
#get values for these arguments from argparse.
     f.write('blah')
```

I would love to know what y'all think of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile

class infile(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name=None):
        self.file_name = file_name
    def __enter__(self):
        if self.file_name is None:
             self.f = sys.stdin
        else:
             self.f = open(self.file_name)
        return self.f
    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        if self.f is not sys.stdin:
            self.f.close()
    def __getattr__(self, val):
        return getattr(self.f, val) # pass on other attributes to the underlying filelike object

class outfile(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name=None, *, infile_name=None, inplace=False):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.infile_name = infile_name
        self.inplace = inplace
    def __enter__(self):
        if self.inplace or (self.file_name and self.file_name == self.infile_name):
            self.f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+t', delete=False)
            self.tmppath = self.f.name
        elif self.file_name is None:
            self.f = sys.stdout
            self.tmppath = None
        else:
            self.f = open(self.file_name, 'w')
            self.tmppath = None
        return self.f
    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        # If got no errors...
        if etype is None and self.tmppath:
            self.f.flush()
            shutil.copy(self.tmppath, self.infile_name)
        if self.f is not sys.stdout:
            self.f.close()
        if self.tmppath:
            os.remove(self.tmppath)
    def __getattr__(self, val):
        return getattr(self.f, val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the files you're dealing with are already context managers, *including* `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`. Delegating to them instead of reinventing the wheel, your `infile` class becomes a trivial function:

```
def infile(filename=None):
    if filename is None:
        return sys.stdin        
    return open(filename)
```

`outfile` isn't quite as easy as that, but we can still simplify it a little. First, the `inplace` flag completely changes the behaviour of the function (causes it to choose between mostly disjoint codepaths), and would usually be specified as a literal in the source. It makes more sense to have it as a separate function instead. If you do need to decide between them based on user input, you can always write a short wrapper function.

I'll reuse the name `outfile` for the clobbering version, and use `atomic_update` for the non-clobbering version. The clobbering version is then really just as simple as `infile`:

```
def outfile(filename=None):
    if filename is None:
        return sys.stdout
    return open(filename, 'w')
```

The updating version really does need to do some extra stuff after it the files get closed. So it does need to be it's own context manager. But instead of writing it as a class, it's a little easier to use the stdlib `contextlib` to write it as a coroutine:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def atomic_update(filename):
    if filename is None:
        f = sys.stdout
    else:
        f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+t', delete=False)
        tmppath = f.name

    with f:
        yield f

    if filename is not None:
        shutil.copy(tmppath, filename)
        os.remove(tmppath)
```

nb. It would be nice if we just return `sys.stdout` like in the other cases, but the `contextmanger` decorator considers it an error if the generator doesn't yield exactly once.

As it is, this is a little bit cumbersome to use effectively - you need to open the file for input *separately* (the tempfile is returned empty), and then it's probably a good idea to be careful to close them in the right order. It also loses, eg, file permissions, which isn't ideal. You might want to copy the original file (and metadata) into the temp file, and then `shutil.move` it back when you're done.

Comment: Well, that's a heck of a lot simpler than my code, much thanks :P

Comment: The thing that I worried about, when writing a patch for `argparse.FileType` is how to keep the context from trying to `close` the `stdin/out`.  One way was to wrap them in a dummy context manager, with a 'do nothing' close.

Comment: Your code does a different thing. The OP's context managers do not close `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout` your context managers close them.

Comment: @hpaulj Meanwhile I learned more about context managers. I think for optional context manager it is best to use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) --- for a file you will call `.enter_context()` to include the file into the stack of context managers for `stdin`/`stdout` you will not call it and it will not be handled by the context manager.